# Get two weeks of data but group by a period of 7 days

Tags: mysql

I am looking to run a query that collects the number of results over the last 14 days, this is fairly easy and achieved like so:

```
SELECT COUNT(id) 
FROM table_name
```

What I'd like to do is then group the results so that I can show this week and the previous week. Using the `WEEK()` option in MySQL allows me to get the previous two weeks worth of data, but grouping by weeks can return either 2 or 3 results depending on which week of the year the results fall into:

For example:

```
SELECT WEEK(date_logged) as week, COUNT(id) as rows 
FROM table_name
WHERE date_logged > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 14 DAY) 
GROUP BY WEEK(date_logged)
```

produces:

```
week 38: 10 result
week 39: 20 results
week 40: 3 results
```

rather than:

```
this week: 13 results (10 from week 38 and half of week 39)
previous week: 20 results (half of week 39 and all of week 40)
```

Hopefully that dataset illustrates what I'm after.

If possible, I'd like to avoid doing a `select` on a `select` and hopefully I'm not too far what I'm looking for.

Comment: how are you going to determine the 7 day period?  Is it grouped by the past 7 days from the day of the query or what?

Comment: Do you want days back 14-8 as 'last week' and days back 7-1 as 'previous week' ?

Comment: @bluefeet it will always be 7 days from `NOW()` & @rfusca it should have said this week & last week, will update the question

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
    SELECT 'last week' AS week, COUNT(*) AS rows 
    FROM table_name
    WHERE date_logged >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL  6 DAY 
      AND date_logged  < CURDATE() + INTERVAL  1 DAY
  UNION ALL
    SELECT 'previous week' AS week, COUNT(*) AS rows 
    FROM table_name 
    WHERE date_logged >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 13 DAY
      AND date_logged  < CURDATE() - INTERVAL  6 DAY ;
```